# Comparing every column in a dataframe with a series which has multiple values per cell -Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of answers eg.

`answers=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5,size=(29, 10)))`,

that need to be compared an answer key.

```
In[1]: keyslist.head()

Out[1]: 
0       4
1       3
2       1, 3
3       3
4       2
```

Some questions have more than 1 correct answer. I want to be able to compare **each cell in each column in answers** to the corresponding cells in keyslist. If the values are the same, append a counter for numcorrect=list() and if the values are not the same, append a  counter for numwrong=list().

Here is what I have so far:

```
for j in range(answers.shape[1]):#iterate over rows
    ne=0
    nc=0
    nw=0
    for i in range(answers.shape[0]):
        if str(answers.iloc[i, j])=='nan':
            ne+=1
           
        elif answers.iloc[i, j]==keys[j]:
            nc+=1
            
        else:
            nw+=1
    nwrong.append(nw)
    nempty.append(ne)  
    ncorrect.append(nc)
```

This works for when keyslist has one value per cell. I need help figuring out how to get it to work when
keyslist has more than value in some cells.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```py
answers.iloc[i, j] in [int(x) for x in str(keyslist.iloc[i, 0]).split(',')]
```

- Say your `keyslist` is a dataframe with one column 0. `keyslist.iloc[i, 0]` gets the ith row data in 0 column.
- `str(keyslist.iloc[i, 0])` converts it to string.
- `str(keyslist.iloc[i, 0]).split(',')` splits the more than 1 correct answers into list.
- `[int(x) for x in str(keyslist.iloc[i, 0]).split(',')]` converts the comma separates answers to list of int.
- `answers.iloc[i, j] in ..` checks if the student's answer in the answer list.

Comment: @NEA **If your question is solved**, say thank you by ***accepting** the solution that is **best for your needs***. The **accept check** is below the up/down arrow at the top left of the answer. A new solution can be accepted if a better one shows up. If you have a reputation of 15 or greater, you may also vote on the quality of an answer, with the up or down arrow. **Leave a comment if a solution doesn't answer the question**. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?. Thank you.